# How to activate mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I know that this question have been asked several times. But I can't get it to work.

I installed Apache2 in my Ubuntu server I can also confirm that mod_rewrite is installed using phpinfo();. I have also put a file called .htaccess in my root folder(/var/www/.htaccess). In my .htaccess file I paste the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^.*$ test.php
```

So everything is redirected to test.php

But it still doesn't work. So I checked my httpd.conf file under /etc/apache2. It is completely empty, with no lines of code (This seems a little odd to me)?! However checking in Stackoverflow answers there should be at least the following code in httpd.conf:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Directory>
```

So I paste that code in httpd.conf. And restarted Apache with `sudo /etc/init.d/apache restart`. And it still does not work?

I have also tested to open the file /sites-enabled/000-default and /sites-available/default, where all virtual host settings lies and change under the directory `/var/www` and `/` to AllowOverride All. The mod_rewrite still doesn't work. Can anyone please help me. This problem has been baking my nuts for a while.

Also, my apache2.conf file doesn't work. I tried to write som nonsense. And it is still gives me the normal result instead of http 500 error

Comment: If you're using a standard configuration then your basic document root settings will be in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default if that is what you are looking for. There you can insert AllowOverride All which will allow rewriting via the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All suggestions from Niels Bom are the smartest ones (I think). But I would add this as the first suggestion: try to launch and stop apache via the Ubuntu command: then when it's supposed to be stopped, *make sure* it's stopped ie verify your local page doesn't show anymore.

- read what's in the folder `/etc/apache2/`. There should be `apache2.conf  conf.d  envvars  httpd.conf  mods-available  mods-enabled  ports.conf  sites-available  sites-enabled`
- then if everything is ok, take a look at `mods-enabled` where you will find if the mods are enabled if so, then you can go on, otherwise take a look at the other answers about enabling modrewrite
- take a look at `sites-enabled`: it's where you can find the sites that are... (guess what?) enabled. There should be the `default` website.
- if so, open this file, and try to put apache nonsense in it, restart the server and see if it's happy or not. If it's not happy that's good. If it's happy then you're working on the wrong file
- last: try to check **what are the authorisations for htaccess files** for this default vhost. Here's the way they work: if Apache doesn't find any directive in the vhost file, it will apply the global configuration. So I'd suggest to add the configuration in your vhost file, between the `<virtualhost>` - `</virtualhost>` tags (of course).

Please tell me what's going on and I'd be glad to update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

if you run this command,

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

ubuntu will output whethere it is activated or already running.

Comment: This will not work. The configs need to be rewritten by hand.

Answer (score 5):

*Because this thread ranks very high on google, here another solution:*

**WHAT'S CAUSING THE PROBLEM ?**

It's caused because the standard definition in apache simply blocks all .htaccess stuff. Seriouslsy. This seems to be the initial state in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

**SOLUTION**

In /etc/apache2/sites-available/default (that's a file, not a folder) there's a code block like

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here you should change

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

**IMPORTANT**

You have to do these changes with sudo rights, anotherwise Ubuntu will not save the file. After a RESTART your .htaccess stuff should work. To test .htaccess simply put some nonsense text into it and surf to localhost or 127.0.0.1 -> If you see "internal server error": voila! Remove the nonsense and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, let's check assumptions:

1. Put nonsense in your Apache config files (and restart Apache to let them take effect), does Apache "complain" on restart? Then it tries to load those files. Try this for every Apache config file you can find. You now have a complete list of Apache config files that are loaded.
2. put nonsense in your htaccess, reload the page, do you get a 500 error? If not, the htaccess is not getting loaded.
3. Put the most basic mod_rewrite statement in your htaccess:

   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^.*$ test.html

This should rewrite every request to test.html.

Try this and give us the results.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I thought my htaccess worked, but it didnt. I tested your three steps and none of them works as expected. Do you have en idea what to do. Step 1 & 2 are not giving me an http 500 error and 3 is bypassed by the server

Comment: If Apache does not complain on restart if you've put nonsense in an Apache config file, then Apache is not reading that config file. Could you give us a complete listing of every file and its contents in /etc/apache2/ ?

Comment: Just to be clear: with "Apache config file" I mean any file in /etc/apache2/ and *not* your .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Please check `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: I check again, and in my installation the directory directive is in: /etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf. make sure the alias module is enabled

Comment: I have that file? What shall I do with it?

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you have mentioned,

> Also, my apache2.conf file doesn't work. I tried to write som nonsense. And it is still gives me the normal result instead of http 500 error

So, before posting more stuff to try-out with .conf files,

run `strace -o somefilename.txt sudo /etc/init.d/apache restart`

strace - trace system calls and signals : [strace(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)**.**

---

The `-o somefilename.txt` part puts the output of `strace` into `somefilename.txt`. Open the text file and search for `httpd.conf`. You should be able to see code similar to:

```
stat("/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=35894, ...})=0
open("/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

The path to `httpd.conf` will be replaced by the path to your default `httpd.conf`

If you find one, then open that `httpd.conf` and make changes there. Else, a `httpd.conf` is not getting loaded.

If later is the case, try:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache -f  /path/to/httpd.conf start
```

---

Also, check for `NameVirtualHost *:80` and make sure it is not commented.