# oxwall .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, oxwall

This is my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

AddEncoding gzip .gz
AddEncoding gzip .gzip
<FilesMatch "\.(js.gz|js.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css.gz|css.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/http-bind
RewriteRule (.*) /http-bind [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_cron/run\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.xml|\.feed|robots\.txt|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

Oxwall version 1.4.1. When I browse to localhost it's redirect me to localhost/install/requirements/ with message - The requested URL /install/requirements was not found on this server. 
When I browse to localhost/index.php installation start but after installation the oxwall doesn't work properly.

Comment: "version 1.4.1" of which software? Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The requested URL /install/requirements was not found on this server."

I guess you need to [activate `mod_rewrite`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628907/how-to-activate-mod-rewrite) first in your server.

Comment: I think that problem is in .htaccess file

Comment: If it is the Oxwall default .htaccess, which is working for many other users, it can't be the problem…

Comment: Yes. It's a default. I always have a problem with .htaccess files.
I check httpd.conf and mod_rewrite is ON

Comment: I never saw an Apache version where `mod_rewrite` was enabled inside `httpd.conf`. There should exist a symlink: `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load -> ../mods-available/rewrite.load`; if not enable that mod with `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. And if as you wrote, you always have problems with `.htaccess` files, you really should check your server setup first. Also check the Apache `error.log`.

Comment: I find the problem.
I change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable mod_rewrite in web server.
2. Keep your Oxwall files and folders in your web root.
3. Try with this url : localhost/install.

This works for me.