# Opencart Redirect to www.localhost.com

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, opencart

I have downloaded OpenCart project from live site, and put in localhost.
Changed catalog/config.php and admin/config.php

Problem is, when I enter url: localhost/xyz, it get redirect to www.localhost.com

**config.php**:

```
<?php
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/xyz/');
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://localhost/xyz/');

define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'C:\xxampp\htdocs\xyz/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'C:\xxampp\htdocs\xyz/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', 'C:\xxampp\htdocs\xyz/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'C:\xxampp\htdocs\xyz/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'C:\xxampp\htdocs\xyz/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'C:\xxampp\htdocs\xyz/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'C:\xxampp\htdocs\xyz/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'C:\xxampp\htdocs\xyz/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'C:\xxampp\htdocs\xyz/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'C:\xxampp\htdocs\xyz/system/logs/');

define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'xyz_abc');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'xyz_');
?>
```

**.htaccess**:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 
# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.
# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes
# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you     folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following     settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off
# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M
# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product  options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Above file is .htaccess file, tried most relevant code, but yet not working.

Comment: show your config file data

Comment: there may be problem with http server configuration. please show htaccess

Comment: how can I put code in stackoverflow, i am new here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting - check this link to add code to your question.

Comment: `catalog/config.php` ?? It should be outside the catalog folder. Admin config file needs to be inside the admin folder and frontend config.php needs to be outside the catalog folder (ie, in the root folder along with the main `index.php` file)

Comment: @PANKAJRAUT : Can you post your config file paths? Both for admin as well as client side. And if you have a `.htaccess` file in your root, paste that also..

Comment: @Roy M J  :
hello sir, what it should be now..?????

Answer (score 1):

Your RewriteBase is wrong in your .htaccess file. According to you, your code is like this today:

```
#RewriteBase /
```

But it should look like this:

```
RewriteBase /xyz/
```

Please, note that you must check if `mod_rewrite` is turned on in your Apache config, as so the `AllowOverride` directive (`All` or `FileInfo`). Also, if your installation has a .htaccess file inside the root directory, it may be relevant.

About the mod_rewrite configuration, I'd recommend [this post](http://drgeek.com.br/2013/tutorial-como-usar-htaccess-parte-2-habilitando-e-configurando-o-mod_rewrite/) (in Portuguese) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628907/how-to-activate-mod-rewrite) (in English).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with defining first for localhost and after for virtualhost. for example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost [nc]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

if used alias after localhost then after ^localhost [nc]

change /index.php?url=$1 to /yourwebaliasname/index.php?url=$1