# How to run htaccess rewrite code on localhost

Tags: php, localhost

```
   SecFilterEngine Off
    DirectorySlash Off
    Options -Indexes

    ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php
    ErrorDocument 403 /not-found.php

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.com.au$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://someurl.au/$1 [R=301,L]

    # RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
    # RewriteRule ^$ ? [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^news_and_events.asp news-and-views? [NC,R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^detailapplication.asp products/applications? [NC,R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^detailproduct.asp products/products? [NC,R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^detailproduct.asp products/products? [NC,R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^products.asp products/products? [NC,R=301,L]
```

This code is properly working on server but it is not working on localhost. Please someone tell me the necessary changes. In that url is there i think need changes in that url as localhost, i have add localhost there but still not working please tell me the issue

Comment: maybee you don't have not all apache mods loaded to use ``SecFilterEngine`` or even ``ModRewrite``? If you tell us what exactly not works this would be fine eg. you get a ``Internal Server Error`` or just the ``RewriteRules`` are not working...

Comment: Server error! error no 500

Comment: look my first comment

Comment: i got server error 500, how to resolve please tell me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different folder for your project, Add your folder name in RewriteBase like below.

```
RewriteBase /YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/
```

also remove following lines. It's not necessary for localhost.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://someurl.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: need to configure on localhost

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest turning on the rewrite log so you can see what is actually happening.

I dont know what version of apache you are using or even the OS so try adding this to your httpd.conf or the Virtual Host definition for this site but **not in the .htaccess file**

For Apache 2.2 [rewrite log Doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "full/path/to/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

If you are using Apache 2.4 [rewrite log Doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) the syntax has changed to something like this

```
RewriteEngin On
RewriteLog "full/path/to/rewrite.log"
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to remove `SecFilterEngine Off` as it requires mod_security which is not installed by default.

If it still doesn't work check your httpd.conf. mod_rewrite needs to be activated. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8861104/2898712)

If it still doesn't work maybe [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is set to none.